# How to use authlib without https

Tags: python, oauth, authlib

I would like to know if there is a way to tell [authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib) to ignore the lack of HTTPS in my dev environment instead of throwing an `InsecureTransportError`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned [here](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/common/security.py) you can set an environment variable :

```
export AUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=1
```

Or if you want to set it programmatically

```
# Somewhere in webapp_example.py, before the app.run for example
import os 
os.environ['AUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
```